# Why does my output execute multiple print functions?

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

I'm working on a guessing game where the user inputs a number until they get it correct. I'm trying to understand why my output creates multiple print functions if I don't guess in the first try.  But if I guess the answer correctly on first try, it prints correctly.

```py
ans = 5

def function(guess, ans):
    if ans != guess:
        if ans < guess:
            print("Guess lower")
            return False
        elif ans > guess:
            print("Guess higher")
            return False
    elif ans == guess:
        print("Correct!")

def init():
    print("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
    guess = int(input())
    main(guess)

def main(guess):
    while function(guess, ans) == False:  
        init()
        function(guess, ans)
        break

init()
```

**Outputs:**

Correct guess on first attempt:

```
Guess a number between 1 and 10:
5
Correct!
```

Correct guess on third attempt:

```
Guess a number between 1 and 10:
4
Guess higher
Guess a number between 1 and 10:
6
Guess lower
5
Correct!
Guess lower
Guess higher
```

Comment: You need to trace your program with pencil and paper to see what is going on. Note that when you have lines like: `init()`, then this is what is called `calling` a function. This means that your program first jumps to the function, but after the function completes, it returns to the next line after the call. This effect of call and return can go many levels deep because your fault is that `init()` calls `main()` which calls `init()` etc and only exits the call from `main()` if the result of `function()` is not `False`.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this:

1. The answer is incorrect. So you go to `init()`
2. The `init()` again passes the argument to `main()` function. So, it has become a sort of recursion where the function is executed again.

Here is what your code is doing.

```
main()
|__init()
|  |
|  main()
|  |
|  function()
|
function()
```

That is why you are getting that output.
Also, this hierarchy increases 1 level with each incorrect answer.

Instead, here is what you can do:

```
ans = 5
guess=0
def function(guess, ans):
    if ans != guess:
        if ans < guess:
            print("Guess lower")
            return False
        elif ans > guess:
            print("Guess higher")
            return False
    elif ans == guess:
        print("Correct!")
        return True
def init(guess):
    while True:
        print("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
        guess = int(input())
        if function(guess, ans):
            break

init(guess)
```

Comment: Don't use `global` variable for a new programmer!

Comment: Also you should print `Guess a number between 1 and 10:` just once before calling `init()` or else it will print every time in the while loop.

Comment: @KeshavBajaj, that is what is happening with OP's code

Answer (score 1):

All explanations were given by @Sujay.

This is an alternative with local variable.

```
ans = 5

def guess_my_number(guess, ans):  # <- choose a meaning function name
    if ans != guess:
        if ans < guess:
            print("Guess lower")
            return False
        elif ans > guess:
            print("Guess higher")
            return False
    elif ans == guess:
        print("Correct!")
        return True  # <- It's important to return True

def main():
    # If user guessed the answer, this variable is set to True
    good_answer = False
    # So while the user has not found, continue to ask him a number
    while good_answer != True:
        print("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
        guess = int(input())
        good_answer = guess_my_number(guess, ans)

main()
```

Comment: Ok, what is `good_answer`? You set it once and test it in the `while`, but it never changes after that!

Comment: @quamrana. Sorry typo. I fixed it and ty.

Comment: Ok, also, btw, the way you have your code, the `return True` is not actually needed, even though its what you would expect.

Comment: I know but I think it's important for OP for his learning. I could test `good_answer != True`

Comment: Ok, now its better.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that when your input isn't correct the first time, your code is entering into a recursive call because of the `main(guess)` line that you've put in the `init()` function which later is returning those extra lines of output that you don't want to see. (For `n` incorrect tries, you'll be seeing `n` such extra lines after your code prints out Correct! depending on whether your previous inputs were higher or lower.)

First, there is no need of `ans != guess`, you can simply make a conditional with `if-elif-else` condition like:

```
def function(guess, ans):
    if ans < guess:
        print("Guess lower")
        return False
    elif ans > guess:
        print("Guess higher")
        return False
    else: # This will automatically be ans = guess case 
        print("Correct!")
        return True # You weren't returning any value here and I suppose you wanted to exploit this
```

You'll need to remove the `main(guess)` line from your `init()` function to avoid recursive-call and add a line to return guess i.e. user input so that you can pass it on to the `main()` function.

```
def init():
    print("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ")
    guess = int(input())
    return guess
```

Now, you need to modify your main function like-

```
def main():
    while True:  
        guess = init()
        if function(guess, ans):
            break
```

You can call the main function as shown below and it'll work-

```
main()
```

PS- There are many ways to fix your code into the one which does what you wish to do and this is just one of those ways.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `function(guess, ans)` in the `main()` function. you are already using `while` loop and returning bool values from `function()`

Answer (score 0):

In the function function () return true when value is satisfied